# How to do pivoting with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have a MySQL table:

[image]

I want output something like below (kind of pivoting), value in Pen Pencil and Glue column has to be populated from the recent timestamp.

[image]

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: I tried this query :
select 
category,
max(if(`product` = 'pen',flag,null))as 'Pen',
max(if(`product` = 'pen',flag,null))as 'Pencil',
max(if(`product` = 'pen',flag,null))as 'Glue'
from Product_Table 

This is giving me output but ,i am not sure how to retrieve the flag value for the latest timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your result by doing a pivot of a subquery which identifies the latest records for each `Category` - `Product` group.

```
SELECT t1.Category,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t1.Product = 'pen'    THEN CONCAT(t1.Flag, '(productid-', t1.Product_ID, ')') ELSE NULL END) AS Pen,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t1.Product = 'pencil' THEN CONCAT(t1.Flag, '(productid-', t1.Product_ID, ')') ELSE NULL END) AS Pencil,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t1.Product = 'glue'   THEN CONCAT(t1.Flag, '(productid-', t1.Product_ID, ')') ELSE NULL END) AS Glue
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Category, Product, MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Category, Product
) t2
    ON t1.Category  = t2.Category AND
       t1.Product   = t2.Product AND
       t1.timestamp = t2.timestamp
GROUP BY t1.Category
```

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Thankyou Tim so much ...it worked for me .u saved my day

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select
    Category,
    max(case when Product = 'pen' then concat(`Flag`, '(productid-', Product_ID, ')') else null end) as `Pen`,
    max(case when Product = 'pencil' then concat(`Flag`, '(productid-', Product_ID, ')') else null end) as `Pencil`,
    max(case when Product = 'glue' then concat(`Flag`, '(productid-', Product_ID, ')') else null end) as `Glue`
from (
    select t1.*
    from yourtable t1
    join (
        select Product, Category, max(`timestamp`) as `timestamp`
        from yourtable
        group by Product, Category
    ) t2 on t1.Product  = t2.Product and t1.`timestamp` = t2.`timestamp` and t1.Category = t2.Category
) t
group by Category
```

Comment: Thankyou for the fast reply ,this too worked for me .Thankyou so much :)